# Is there any way to mask out parts of a texture to make it a different colour to the rest?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shader-nodes

Been following this really great tutorial from "Critical Giants" on how to make procedural planets, and to begin, I wanted to try making an Earth-like planet.

While I've got a decent understanding of how these nodes work together, I'm not exactly sure how I could go about making the top land mass white (as if it was the north pole), or even how I'd make certain parts of the planet different colours (like parts of the ocean green, making certain land masses more green than others, etc). Is there a way to mask out that particular area of the texture? Kind of like how you would do it in After Effects or Photoshop?

For reference:

https://pasteboard.co/DmuhMHn5WOSF.jpg - current render of the planet

https://pasteboard.co/WoJH1F8cLSKO.png - nodes (just for the planet, atmosphere & clouds are separate models)

This has all been done in Eevee.

Hopefully, that made sense, and thanks for anyone's help in advance!

Comment: try the mix node, use the factor with a factor from a built in texture or paint an image on your mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

You can use Black and White values to control which color or shader gets passed through a mix node. Plug  black and white values(non-color) to the factor socket in the node editor.

This doesn't have to be pure Black and white values, any light/dark values will work. If you already have an image texture, try tweaking making the brighter values brighter and darker values darker with curves node and use them as a factor map.

Procedural texturing is a topic on its own, an example :
Here I have used the math node to add two Gradient textures which resulted in a new gradient texture, and then used that resulting gradient to mask out parts of a checker texture.

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you! I've tried to use this now, but still am struggling to get it working how I want it. How can I stop the checker texture from covering the whole planet? And is there any way I can change the shape so it covers the top island more easily? Sorry for all the questions, I'm quite new to node editing overall.

here's an img reference for where I'm at: 
https://pasteboard.co/l5Ig0Qe7aXjO.png
https://pasteboard.co/TlzxaCHCWyOs.png

Comment: I have edited the answer, in short you can combine masks like adding and cutting to get the desired texture you want.

Comment: Thanks again! This has been super helpful. One more question, is there any way I can make it so that the mask only affects the land mass and not the ocean?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Agnivesh's answer, if you need to mix 2 materials that have different shaders (for example you need to mix 2 *Principled BSDF* that have different settings), mix them through a *Mix Shader*, with your black and white image or noise as factor:

[image]